# com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException: BODYSTRUCTURE parse error: bad ``size'' element

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to read the Bounce mails from an email inbox and I always get the following exception:

```
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com) DEBUG IMAPS: ignoring bad response, THROW: 
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com) com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException: BODYSTRUCTURE parse error: bad ``size'' element
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.<init>(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:266)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.<init>(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:291)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.<init>(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:110)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.parseItem(FetchResponse.java:258)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.parse(FetchResponse.java:213)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.<init>(FetchResponse.java:96)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:392)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.command(Protocol.java:354)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetch(IMAPProtocol.java:2113)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetch(IMAPProtocol.java:2105)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetchBodyStructure(IMAPProtocol.java:1680)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadBODYSTRUCTURE(IMAPMessage.java:1476)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getDataHandler(IMAPMessage.java:746)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1454)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailBinding.extractBodyFromMail(MailBinding.java:250)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailMessage.createBody(MailMessage.java:105)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailMessageRobust.createBody(MailMessageRobust.java:39)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:47)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.createExchanges(MailConsumer.java:354)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:128)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPool
Executor.java:180)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecuto
r.java:294)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2019-05-23 16:05:42 INFO  [stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter] (Camel (camel-inbound) thread #24 - robustimaps://abc@test.com)       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried to look up on the internet so what this error means, but I am not really getting any useful results. Any recommendation or hint in the direction would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

After reading the comment from @arnt I have extracted the response which throws this error and it is as follows:

```
robustimaps://abc@test.com) * 1 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE (((("text" "plain" ("charset" "UTF-8") NIL NIL "7BIT" 143 7 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("text"
 "html" ("charset" "UTF-8") NIL NIL "7BIT" 1209 33 NIL NIL NIL NIL) "alternative" ("boundary" "0000000000006a31d605898e6fe4") NIL NIL)("image" "png" ("name" "icon.png") "<icon.png>" NIL "base64" 7864 NIL ("attachment" ("filename" 
"icon.png")) NIL NIL) "related" ("boundary" "0000000000006a31d305898e6fe3") NIL NIL)("message" "delivery-status" NIL NIL NIL "7BIT" 355 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("message" "rfc822" NIL NIL NIL "7BIT" 0 ("Thu, 23 May 2019 15:55:30 +0200" "=
?UTF-8?Q?Ihr_blah_blah_blah_bald._when_and_where_m=C3=B6c?= =?UTF-8?Q?hten_Sie_es_empfangen=3F_Jetzt_festlegen_...?=" (("ABC Paket" NIL "abc" "test.com")) NIL (("ABC Paket" NIL "abc" "test.com")) ((NIL NIL "3011941477" "xyz.
de")) NIL NIL NIL "<2066153904.661086.1558619730208@rnd-02.broadmail.live>") ("multipart" "signed" ("protocol" "application/pkcs7-signature" "micalg" "sha-256" "boundary" "----=_Part_661085_623173410.1558619730208") NIL NIL "7BIT"
 -1 NIL NIL NIL NIL) 0 NIL NIL NIL NIL) "report" ("boundary" "0000000000006a30fa05898e6fdb" "report-type" "delivery-status") NIL NIL))
```

Comment: Javamail was parsing a bodystructure, which is a very long line with many parens, numbers, NILs and strings. At a  point where it expected a size it found a negative number. Why was there a negative number there? Well, IMAP servers don't have many occasions to send negative numbers, so I suspect a server bug.

Comment: I have extracted a response which throws this error and added it to my question above. I do see a negative number there "-1" right after "7BIT". But what does it mean and how would one go about resolving it? Btw, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: The server is telling javamail that one of the bodyparts is -1 octets long, and javamail gives up. This particular number isn't used by javamail AFAIK, so if your application doesn't use it either you could patch javamail. Or you could report the bug to the server author.

Comment: Yes, your server is definitely broken.  Please report the bug to your server vendor.  What server are you using?  (JavaMail does use the size to determine how much it can read.)

Comment: It is an IMAPv4 Server. Server is third party managed so the maximum I can do is file a bug report. Thanks a lot for the responses. @arnt Can you post your comment also as an answer, then I can accept it :)

Comment: @BillShannon I thought javamail's reading depeds only on the size given at the start of each literal?

Comment: @arnt It does for each piece, but the size in the BODYSTRUCTURE controls how much it asks for.  It stops asking when it has read the total size.  It is capable of ignoring the size and reading until there is no more returned, but that only works if the size is valid but wrong.  "-1" is an invalid size.  JavaMail should probably be more tolerant of that server error; I'll consider that for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Javamail was parsing a bodystructure, which is a very long line with many parens, numbers, NILs and strings. At a point where it expected a size it found a negative number. Why was there a negative number there? Well, IMAP servers don't have many occasions to send negative numbers, so I suspect a server bug.

(For completeness: The alternative would be that the server's number was correct and that the client was wrong to expect a size at that point. But we now know that it was a server bug.)